# Probability of coin to show head

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the below question .

[image]

The answer is given as

[image]

I could not understand how they have written the sample space (term in denominator)  .

Comment: Reading the tag-wiki, I do not think [tag:probability] nor [tag:probability-distributions] are appropriate tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Norm the probabilities so 
$$
\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1.
$$
That means that 
$$
\overbrace{p}^A + \overbrace{(1-p)p}^B + \overbrace{(1-p)^2p}^C = p^3-3p^2+3p = 1-(1-p) ^3,
$$
which is your denominator.

Comment: Why their sum is one

Comment: Because one of them eventually have to get heads; the probability of never seeing a heads is zero.